# Delete image in app document directory

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have 24 images in a "PhotoAlbum" folder in my app document directory. How to delete a selected image in the "PhotoAlbum"? How do I pass the object index?

I have something like this:

```
- (id <MWPhoto>)photoBrowser:(MWPhotoBrowser *)photoBrowser photoAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
    {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/PhotoAlbum"];

    NSString *fullPath = [dataPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[self.photos objectAtIndex:index]];
    NSData *pngData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fullPath];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:pngData];

    MWPhoto *photo = [[MWPhoto alloc] initWithImage:image];
    return photo;
}
```

Comment: ohk..create your image with unique name say myImage1, myImage2, myImage3,......etc and save them in your folder. Here 1,2,3,...are nothing but only index. Now just fire the delete option for selected index images. Hope u get me

Answer (score 0):

You can't delete it by specifying an index. You have to specify the image name you wanted to delete. It will be something like this

```
NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",documentPath,image.imageName];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:documentPath]){
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:filePath error:&error];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will delete your image and return deleted image.

```
 - (id <MWPhoto>)photoBrowser:(MWPhotoBrowser *)photoBrowser photoAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
    {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/PhotoAlbum"];

    NSString *fullPath = [dataPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[self.photos objectAtIndex:index]];
    NSData *pngData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fullPath];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:pngData];

    MWPhoto *photo = [[MWPhoto alloc] initWithImage:image];
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:fullPath]){
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:fullPath error:&error];
    }

    return photo;
}
```

Comment: Hi, if I want to put my delete image code in this function?                                                    - (void)photoBrowser:(MWPhotoBrowser *)photoBrowser deletebuttonPressedforPhotoAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index